Identify this Haro bmx
Can anyone identify this Haro serial number please on the bottom of the bike it has ×2 HADA0701995

It is a Haro bike with a readable serial number. Those numbers are important to report a bike stolen and that is about it. Please edit in some photos of the bike and what you need to know about the bike.

As a new user, you might want to take the tour.  It will help you formulate good questions, answers, and understand how Bicycles Stack Exchange (and other Exchange sites) operate.  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour

Also see this question and its answers: https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1337/18917
